# Verify if all the messages sent in a queue are being consumed by the application

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, messaging

I am using JMS(Fiorano provider) as a synchronization between the two applications. 
App-A will publish a message on the Topic of there is any data changes to App-B so that the App-B can update its state.

Now the issue that I am facing is that all the messages that are sent from App-A is not read by App-B as a result there is a data inconsistency between the two applications.

That is the back story! Thank you if you have read through it so far..

Here are my questions :

1. Is there a way to get the list of all the messages that are being published by App-A which are not read by App-B
2. What might be the root cause for App-b failing to read few messages?

Please help me sort this through.

Comment: If your publication topic of App-A is the same as the subscription topic of App-B, every messages published should also be received by App-B if App-B starts subscribing before the first publication ?!? Or am I missing something? Can please clarify what you mean by data inconsistency ?

Comment: Yes.. APP-A sends messages on a same topic which App-B listens to. And App-B will process the messages fine. But intermittently App-B fails to receive some messages which are sent from App-A

Comment: Ok - if messages are failing to be delivered, there's an issue. Maybe your message size is too big to be delivered ? To improve message guarantees, you could try to make a durable subscription, or even better use a transacted session and call session.commit() after every message you received.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a message is delivered or consumed by the consumer you have to use ActiveMQ Advisory Messages.
On producer side you subscribe to the correspondant destination to be notified of each consumed message but you have to keep an updated list of sent messages to know which ones are not yet consumed...

The app-b can fail to read messages if it freezes...

if you want AMQ discards messages not treated after some time you can use 
**JMSExpiration**

> Time in milliseconds to expire the message. A value of 0 means never expire.
>   http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-message-properties.html

http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

Here is a basic example of code :

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.command.MessageId;

public class AdvisorySupportGetMessageConsumedAdvisoryTopic {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        final Set<MessageId> sentMessages = new HashSet<MessageId>();
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            ConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
            conn = cf.createConnection();
            ActiveMQSession session = (ActiveMQSession) conn.createSession(false,
                    ActiveMQSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            conn.start();
            Queue q = session.createQueue("q");
            Destination advisoryDestination = org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisorySupport
                    .getMessageConsumedAdvisoryTopic(q);
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(advisoryDestination);
            consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(Message msg) {
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    System.out.println(((ActiveMQMessage) msg).getMessageId());
                    sentMessages.remove(((ActiveMQMessage) msg).getMessageId());
                }
            });
            MessageProducer advisoryProducer = session.createProducer(q);
            TextMessage resp = session.createTextMessage("text");
            advisoryProducer.send(resp);
            sentMessages.add(((ActiveMQMessage) resp).getMessageId());
            System.out.println(((ActiveMQMessage) resp).getMessageId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```